# Insert bash variable (positional parameter) inside GraphQL cURL with JSON Payload

Tags: json, bash, graphql, alias

I am creating an alias in bash that delivers a GraphQL cURL that contains a JSON payload. Within this payload I would like to include a bash parameter/variable ($1), however the request fails when I use the variable, however it is successful when I specify the value or ID within the payload.

```
capi_cmd () {
        curl 'https://example.com/content/api' \
        -H 'Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate, br' \
        -H 'Content-Type: application/json' \
        -H 'Accept: application/json' \
        -H 'Connection: keep-alive' \
        -H 'DNT: 1' -H 'Origin: https://example.com' --data-binary \
        '{"query":"query($InputStr:String!) {\n  getInfoById(Id: $InputStr) {\n    details {\n      images {\n        url\n      }\n    }\n  }\n}\n","variables":{"InputStr": "$1"}}' \
        --compressed \
        jq | grep -Eo '(http|https)://[^\"]+' | xargs -n1 curl -O
}
```

Any help that could allow me to resolve this issue would be greatly appreciated :)

Thanks,

Stephen.

Comment: grep and xargs are unneeded here. jq can extract urls on its own, and curl can handle multiple transactions at a single run

Answer (score 1):

Your JSON is enclosed in single-quotes.

Inside single-quotes everything is preserved literally, without exception.

You can either enclose in double-quotes and escape all double-quotes inside your JSON string with a backslash.  Or close the quotes, insert the variable, and then re-enter again.

`'...before'"${variable}"'after...'`

Comment: should my variable look like this:    '{"query":"query($InputStr:String!) {\n  getHotelByCmdId(cmdId: $InputStr) {\n    details {\n      images {\n        url\n      }\n    }\n  }\n}\n","variables":{"InputStr": "${1}"}}'

Comment: No.  `'{"query":"query($InputStr:String!) {\n getHotelByCmdId(cmdId: $InputStr) {\n details {\n images {\n url\n }\n }\n }\n}\n","variables\":{"InputStr": "'"${1}"'"}}'`.  Thats `"  '  "  ${1}  "  '  "`

Comment: thank you so much - unfortunately, it throws an error though :( I guess I have to spend a little more time troubleshooting my entire query. Nevertheless you've taught me a valuable piece of knowledge :)

Comment: Just bear in mind, anything enclosed in single-quotes will not be parsed.  If you want to inject a variable, you'll need to break out of the single-quoted string.  Also looks like you are missing a pipe between `--compressed` and `jq`